# Use Scrapy to crawl a site with JavaScript

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I need to crawl [this website](http://www.2345.com/jzw/1.htm). It's a brain teaser website, where when you click on a button, it runs a JavaScript to show the answer window.

```
 <tr> 
      <td width="60" bgcolor="#ECF5FF"> <p align="center"><font color="#800000".htm>1</font></p></td>
      <td width="539" bgcolor="#ECF5FF">&nbsp;<font color="#008080">一种东西，东方人的短，西方人的长，结婚后女的就可以用男的这东西，和尚有但是不用它&nbsp;</font> 
      </td>
      <td width="95" bgcolor="#ECF5FF"> <p align="center"> 
          <INPUT onClick="MM_popupMsg('答案：名字&nbsp;')" type=button value=答案 name=button8639 style='font-size:12px;height:18px;border:1px solid black;'>
        </p></td>
    </tr>
```

This is the code I wrote to crawl the questions and the answers. I can successfully get the question, but failed to get the answer. (When I print out the answer, it's an empty `[]`.)

```
    questions = hxs.select('//td[@width="539"]/font/text()').extract()
    answers = hxs.select('//td[@width="95"]/INPUT/@onClick').extract()
```

The answer is the content of the onclick script, i.e.: I want to get this string:

```
MM_popupMsg('答案：名字&nbsp;')
```

This is my spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
import re

class ReviewSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "2345jzw"

    allowed_domains = ['2345.com/jzw']
    start_urls = ['http://www.2345.com/jzw/index.htm']

    page = 1
    while page <= 1:
        url = 'http://www.2345.com/jzw/%d.htm' % page
        start_urls.append(url)
        page = page + 1

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        questions = hxs.select('//td[@width="539"]/font/text()').extract()
        answers = hxs.select('//td[3]/p/INPUT/@onClick').extract()

        print questions
        print answers

        id = 1
        while id <= 50:

            question = questions[id - 1]


            question = re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', str(question.encode('utf8')))
            question = ' '.join(question.split())
            question = question.replace('&', ' ')
            question = question.replace('\'', ' ')
            question = question.replace(',', ';')

            answer = answers[id - 1]

            answer = re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', str(answer.encode('utf8')))
            answer = ' '.join(answer.split())
            answer = answer.replace('&', ' ')
            answer = answer.replace('\'', ' ')
            answer = answer.replace(',', ';')

            file = open('crawled.xml', 'a')

            file.write(question)

            file.write(",")
            file.write(answer)

            file.write("\n")

            file.close()

            id = id + 1
```

I have tried

```
hxs.select('//INPUT/@onClick').extract()
```

but it is still not working. What is wrong with the path?

Note that the question is successfully extracted. The structure of questions and answers are very alike. Why is the answer empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your xpath expression for getting answers is incorrect, instead of

```
//td[3]/p/INPUT/@onClick
```

use

```
//td[3]/p/input/@onclick
```

Also, here's my version of the spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class DmozItem(Item):
    number = Field()
    question = Field()
    answer = Field()


class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["2345.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.2345.com/jzw/1.htm"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        rows = hxs.select('//body/center/table[2]/tr')
        for row in rows:
            item = DmozItem()
            try:
                item['number'] = row.select(".//td[1]/p/font/text()").extract()[0]
                item['question'] = row.select(".//td[2]/font/text()").extract()[0]
                item['answer'] = row.select(".//td[3]/p/input/@onclick").extract()[0][13:-2]
            except:
                continue
            yield item
```

Run it via `scrapy runspider <spider_name.py> --output-format csv --output output.csv` and see results in csv format in `output.csv` file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i guess i forgot the <p> tag for the path.

Comment: Works for you? Then don't forget to accept the asnwer. Thank you.

Comment: my scrapy is lagging. the terminal shows DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState and stay there forever

Comment: i tried to recreate a project. but still the same. the whole mac is lagging when i started to crawl.

Comment: That's strange - the code works for me. Are you using this spider inside of a scrapy project? If yes - try to move it somewhere and run from there. Additionally, what scrapy version are you using?

Comment: I asked another question. Please help me there.

Comment: moving spiders outside the project and run it works fine now. (I didn't move it last time running the spiders.

Comment: the answer is still empty. @alecxe.

Comment: It works - there are 50 questions and answers in the `output.json` file - recheck it please. Plus, why are you writing to the file manually? Scrapy can do it automatically by making use of [Items](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) and different output formats like e.g. for xml: `scrapy runspider --output-format xml --output output.xml`.

Comment: can u try my solution? it seems to be correct. btw, I write it manually for some other reasons

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32330/discussion-between-omgpop-and-alecxe)